# Compatibilidad de Tomcat, Servelets y Jstl en netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Estoy trabajando en un sistema donde debo mostrar datos de una base de datos, estoy usando Jstl y mi server es Tomcat 9, el problema es que al listar demasiados registros ejemplo desde 9 datos no me muestra los datos, lo estoy listando con el foresch de jstl, cambie de servidor a GlassFish y me funciona a la perfección no molesta, si deseo trabajar con tomcat que debo hacer par que me funcionen bien los servlets y la compatibilidad.
Gracias

html

```
<form action="Controlador?menu=Empleado" method="POST">
 <div class="form-group row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                                            <select class="browser-default custom-select" name="area" >
                                                <option selected>Areas</option>
                                                <c:forEach var="areas" items="${areas}">
                                                    <option  value="${areas.getId()}" > ${areas.getArea()} </option>
                                                </c:forEach>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <select class="browser-default custom-select"  name="rol">
                                                <option selected>Roles</option>
                                                <c:forEach var="rol" items="${roles}">
                                                    <option  value="${rol.getId()}" > ${rol.getRol()} </option>
                                                </c:forEach>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div> ${info.getMsjinfo()} </div>
                                    <input type="submit" name="accion" value="Agregar" class="btn btn-primary" >
                                </form>
```

Servlet

```
if (menu.equals("Empleado")) {
            switch (accion) {
                case "Listar"://----> Listar roles y areas
                    List listrol = daorol.listar(); // Lista = el metodo listar de la clase CRolesDAO
                    request.setAttribute("roles", listrol); // Al atributo que se recibe en el html recibe el atributo "roles" para listar los roles
                    List listarea = daoarea.listar();
                    request.setAttribute("areas", listarea);
                    break;
                case "Agregar":
                    try {
                        // Se reciben los campos de texto
                        String nombres = request.getParameter("txtnombres");
                        String apellidos = request.getParameter("txtapellidos");

                        String correo = request.getParameter("txtcorreo");
                        String clave = request.getParameter("txtclave");
                        String clave2 = request.getParameter("txtclave2");


                        if (clave == clave2) {
                            us.setNombres(nombres);
                            us.setApellidos(apellidos);

                            us.setCorreo(correo);
                            us.setClave(clave);



                            daouser.AddUsuario(us); // Se envian los datos al metodo AddUsuario
                        } else {
                            us.setMsjinfo("Las claves no coinciden");
                            request.setAttribute("info", us);
                        }

                        // Se envian los datos por parametro a los datos encapsulados en CUsuario
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        e.getMessage();
                    }


                    request.getRequestDispatcher("Controlador?menu=Empleado&accion=Listar").forward(request, response);


                    break;


                default:
                    throw new AssertionError();
            }

            request.getRequestDispatcher("Empleado.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
```

Comment: Hola. La mejor forma de contarnos cómo lo estás intentando es mostrarnos el código relevante y si sale algún error en los logs de tomcat. Tomcat es compatible con diversas versiones de la especificacíon Servlet, así que posiblemente el lío esté en cómo estás configurando todo

Comment: Ok dejare el código en la edición de mi pregunta, pero si es el código porque en glassfish funciona y en tomcat  no ??

Comment: Cómo lo despliegas en cada contenedor? Desde netbeans? Cómo los configuras?

Comment: Hay algún error en los logs?

Comment: use la librería jstl, <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> pero aún con la ruta no ejecutaba daba error pero cuando agregué la librería directamente en en el proyecto se agrega 2 jstl 1.2.1, hay ya funciono pero no funciono correctamente, el html está bien pero ejemplo pongo unas etiquetas más de html y hay si se desaparece todo todo, Probé con glassfish y puedo poner muchas mas etiquetas y funciona creeria que es algo de compatibilidad ya que tomcat no trae justo y glassfish si, pero se que se puede con tomcat pero nose que versión me puede servir